# Copy Certain Columns From a Filtered List to Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've been working on this project for a while and cannot get the debugger to run clean.  If anyone can get me going in the right direction I would be so thankful!

This workbook filters data from the list ("Soap_List") on the Order Form sheet.  My goal is to press one button to filter the list, and then copy only visible cell from columns A, B, and D to the Echo France Worksheet beginning at cell "C12".

Bonus if you can tell me how to remove the filters after the copy/paste function has been accomplished!

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub cmbPrintEchoFrance_Click() 
    Dim OrderForm As Worksheet
    Dim EchoFrance As Worksheet
    Dim SoapList As ListObject  
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set OrderForm = Worksheets("ORDER FORM")
    Set EchoFrance = Worksheets("ECHO FRANCE")
    Set SoapList = Worksheets("ORDER FORM").ListObjects("SOAP_LIST")

    SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ECHO FRANCE"
    SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

    Set lastRow = OrderForm.Range("A" & OrderForm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set copyRange = OrderForm.Range("A:A" & lastRow)

    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy EchoFrance.Range("C12")


End Sub
```

****UPDATE****
I'm still getting an error message on the lastrow section of the code.  Not sure what to try next.  Is the problem that I am setting a named ListObject?

```
Private Sub cmbPrintEchoFrance_Click()
    Dim OrderForm As Worksheet
    Dim EchoFrance As Worksheet
    Dim SoapList As ListObject


    Set OrderForm = Worksheets("ORDER FORM")
    Set EchoFrance = Worksheets("ECHO FRANCE")

    Set SoapList = Worksheets("ORDER FORM").ListObjects("SOAP_LIST")

    SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ECHO FRANCE"
    SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

    LastRow = SoapList.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    OrderForm.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy EchoFrance.Range("C12")




 End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you can give some detail about where the debugger is stopping and what the error(s) are?

Comment: problem is here `OrderForm.Range("A:A" & lastRow)` - it should be like this for column A: `OrderForm.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`.

Comment: @Bigtree I'm actually having an issue with the code getting past the Set lastRow section.  I keep getting a compile error: Object Required  Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong there...

Comment: I think the problem on the line giving the object required error is that your using `set` which is only needed for seting objects. The line should probably read `lastrow = orderform.range...`.

Comment: @Bigtree I tried that, but still getting an error message. I'm going to post the whole code again as I've changed some things.

Comment: `Soaplist` is what `ListObject`? Is it a Table?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!  Here's the working code as I have it right now.  What I'd really like now is to figure out an If statement that will check if cell "D15" is empty on the PO worksheet and if it is, do not print the page and move to the next part of the code.  Basically, if we are not ordering any soaps from a certain company I do not want that page to be printed.  Any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmbPrintEchoFrance_Click()
    Dim OrderForm As Worksheet
    Dim PO As Worksheet
    Dim SoapList As ListObject
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rngToCopy As Range, rRange As Range

    Set OrderForm = Worksheets("ORDER FORM")
    Set PO = Worksheets("PRINT ORDER")

    Set SoapList = Worksheets("ORDER FORM").ListObjects("SOAP_LIST")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     With OrderForm
     lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Set rRange = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rRange
        'print the Echo France order
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ECHO FRANCE"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
        .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
        PO.Range("E12").Value = "ECHO FRANCE"
        PO.PrintOut
    End With

'clear print order
PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

    With rRange
    'print the european soaps order
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="EUROPEAN SOAPS"
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
    .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
    .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
    PO.Range("E12").Value = "EUROPEAN SOAPS"
    PO.PrintOut
    End With

 'clear print order
PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

    With rRange
    'print the la lavande order
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="LA LAVANDE"
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
    .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
    .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
    PO.Range("E12").Value = "LA LAVANDE"
    PO.PrintOut
    End With

     'clear print order
    PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
    PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

    End With

SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```